# How to create a composite filter that allows multiple selections?

Tags: views

I am using composite views filters in my exposed filters.

I have defined my groups in the composite filter as follows:

- ab = a OR b
- cd = c OR d
- ef = e OR f

However, I only seem to be able to display the options as a dropdown list, with only one selection possible. I'd like users to be able to select both ab and cd together by ticking checkboxes (in other words "ab OR cd").

I've tried doing this using Better Exposed Filters but it doesn't give me any relevant options for the composite filter. (Other filters can be displayed as checkboxes for example)

**Any ideas how I can get multiple selection to work?**